# How to bind search to a controller in a ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I have a html page that has a input search at the top of the page. 
below it I have a  element that loads in a partial. 
I'm trying to have the search bind to the partial. 
It all works if I put the search inside the partial but for learning purposes I want to understand why it wont work outside it and how I could get it to work outside the partial.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="F1FeederApp">
    <div id="nav" ng-controller="driversController">
        <input id="search" type="text" ng-model="nameFilter" placeholder="Serach" />
    </div>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

**app JS**

```
angular.module('F1FeederApp', ['F1FeederApp.controllers','F1FeederApp.services', 'ngRoute']).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when("/drivers", {templateUrl: "partials/drivers.html", controller: "driversController"}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/drivers'});
}]);
```

**Controller.js**

```
angular.module('F1FeederApp.controllers', []).
controller('driversController', function($scope, ergastAPIservice) {
      $scope.nameFilter = null;
      $scope.driversList = [];
        $scope.searchFilter = function(driver){
            var keyword = new RegExp($scope.nameFilter, 'i');
            return !$scope.nameFilter || keyword.test(driver.Driver.givenName) || keyword.test(driver.Driver.familyName);
        }
        ergastAPIservice.getList().success(function(response){
             $scope.driversList = response.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
        });
});
```

Comment: Inside your driversController you set nameFilter to null. Try removing that.

Comment: Oh wait... you're suing the same controller for the partial and the search? Confused....

Answer (score 0):

I think the primary problem is that you've got `driversController` used by the partial and the search area. This puts them in sister scopes. Make a controller in the body and a different one for the partial.

Comment: Ok great but how would I link them to each other. The search needs to be bound to the nameFilter in the scope of driversController

Comment: If it's a child scope, it will inherit, if it's  a sibling scope they wont. So if you've got say "MainController" on the ```body``` HTML tag then ng-view is below that, ng-view scopes will be "child scopes". But you have to remove the ng-controller from ```<div id="nav">``` because that creates a scope next to the ng-view.. i.e. sibling. Make sense?

Comment: So just remove ```$scope.nameFilter=null``` from ```driversController```, and define an empty controller on the body tag. Remove driversController from the first div and now the scope created in the ```body``` tag will automatically pick up ```nameFilter```. Now ```driversController``` is only on your partial, and it will be able to inherit $scope.nameFilter automatically. Actually, it might not because primitives have a hard time inheriting, which is why it's recommended that anything in ```ng-model``` has a dot in it... i.e. ```ng-model="thing.property"```.